# Migrating from Blogengine.net to Orchard

Tags: orchardcms, blogengine.net

I have an existing blog/news site that runs on BE.net 2.6 and i would like to migrate it to Orchard. Right now i am testing the migration locally. I exported the BE.net posts as Blog ML and imported into Orchard. Two rubs - one) Orchard does not pick up the tags in BE and instead see the categories (of which there are only 3) as the tags and two) my excerpts in BE do not appear in Orchard after import. My excerpts typically have short text and an image and i want to be able to show those in the page that lists all the posts. But i do not want the image to appear in the details page. I found the fork of Blog ML that should allow tags to be brought corectly except when using that version the Blog ML options in the dashboard are not present.

You can see the live site (running BE 2.6) here http://nomorecocktails.com. I'd like the listing of posts to appear the same way with the excerpt and image in orchard. And if you can help figure out how to get the tags in too. I'd rather not have to go back through and edit the posts in orchard to ad the tags.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am the author of the BlogML Module. I have had a few reports of BlogEngine.net exports not going in to Orchard correctly, inparticular the Tags...

The people whole reported the initial problem did soem investigation for me and found that the Tags actually dont appear in the export file, i.e. the BlogEngine export does not export the Tags.

Could you please verify this for me? If this is not the case, please reply and I will contact you to get hold of your BlogML file and test the import locally.

The excerpts do not appear in Orchard because the BlogML module was built to only interface with the defautl implementation of the Orchard Blog module. This decision need to be changed. I think Excepts should be going in to the system, and will built it in to the module that will superseed the BlogML module. (https://orchardimportexport.codeplex.com/)

Nick

Comment: Thanks for replying Nick. My tags are being exported. Here is a sample of the xml file:

Comment: It doesnt look like the example got attached. Please email me the file at Jetski5822 at gmail dot com

Comment: Okay so I took a look at your file, and the problem is that the person who wrong the BlogML export tool from the blog engine you use did not follow the BlogML Spec, instead, He followed about 85% of it.... Let me explain,

BlogML does not have a notion of Tags, instead it has a notion of categories, The export file you have have both categories and tags, though alot more tags that categories.

Because Tags dont exist in the spec, they cant be imported.

Does your blog allow you to export in any other format? If so, let me know the format and I will add an importer for you.

Comment: No other formats availabale for export unfortunately Nick. As I see it my options are 1) manually re-enter posts into orchard, 2) stick with BE and wait for an MVC version of it. The more i think about it i will likley stick with BE.Net. Even with many years of asp.net experience i find Orchard to be difficult to customize to my needs.

Comment: That's cool. Sorry I couldnt help anymore, if you ever get back in to it, let me know.

Comment: Does this module work with new version of orchard? I do not see it is listed on the left side after installing. I cannot import for that reason.